# AWS, can I get disk (volume) images sent to me on DVD?

Tags: amazon-ec2

In AWS, can I get disk (volume) images sent to me on DVD?

This would be in preparation to save costs by eliminating the instances and volumes.  It took a year to get everything created, the right instances and structure hierarchy. And experimentation to select the right combinations of instances and volume types.

My company wants to save the monthly costs (for a year or so) but also wants the option and ability to restart everything when they want.

Is it possible to be able to save the whole set-up, remove all the instances and volumes (to eliminate costs), and re-institute it back when needed?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your instance operating system (RedHat, Windows, etc.) you might not be able to get images of the EC2 instance in any form other than AMIs or snaphots stored at Amazon. The reason is Amazon's license does not permit this.

I have not heard of AWS offering a service to back up your data to DVDs. If your goal is to save money, think of the cost per hour that AWS would charge you to manually create DVDs. The DVD write process is slow ....

Instead approach the situation of either creating Amazon Machine Images (AMIs) of your instances or creating snapshots of your instances. You would need to pay the cost of data storage which is about $.05 per GB. 100 GB of data would cost $60.00 per year. 100 GB on DVDs that AWS generated would be significantly higher if offered.

Answer (score 0):

You only can export an image if you import in the first place (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html)

I recommend just creating snapshots, it won't bring the cost to zero but it's cheaper than having stopped instances with unused volumes. If volumes are General Purpose SSD (gp2), snapshots will be half of the price ($0.05 per GB-month)

I definitely don't recommend storing data on DVDs, take advantage of the cloud and the resilience it provides. I'm sure these DVDs won't work when you try to use them after a year if you can even find them, that will cost more than staying on the cloud. :)